# Post files to API with Python requests module

Tags: python

I'm looking to upload a file to an API using the requests module. The API requires the files to be posted using 'files[]'.

I have tried many things to get this to work but I simply can't.

My current code is as following, however the file never gets uploaded.

```
request = requests.post("api here", data = {"files[]": file})
if request.status_code == 200:
    print("upload successful.")
else:
    print("upload unsuccessful...")
print(request.text)
```

If it helps I can post the code for the API as it is open sourced, however it is written in PHP.

Comment: I think you need a keyword argument: `request = requests.post(url, files=file)`

Comment: That doesn't work, it gives an error saying there are 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
file = {"files[]": open('YourFile.txt','rb')}   #Read file in Binary Mode
request = requests.post("api here", files=file)   #Send File in request using files key
if request.status_code == 200:
    print("upload successful.")
else:
    print("upload unsuccessful...")
print(request.text)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. I didn't realize it would be that simple.